# Strange constructor behaviour in nunit parameterized tests

Tags: nunit, resharper

I have a nunit 2.5.10 parameterized test:

```
[TestFixture(parameter1)]
[TestFixture(parameter2)]
public class MyTest : BaseTest
{
   var param="";

   public MyTest(string arg)
   {         
       param=arg;
   }

   [Test]  
   public Test()
   {
      //... test stuff
   }
}
```

In VS 12 with Resharper 7.0.1 I run only one fixture **but!** the constructor is called **twice** - once before test execution (for one parameter) and then after test execution but for another parameter. Why? Only constructor is called twice, test itsself is running as expected - only one time.

Comment: Is this the same in the NUnit GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known problem, unfortunately, see [RSRP-336641](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336641) "When calling certain case on Parametrized TestFixture all cases constructors and TestFixtureSetUp are called."